# Quicksort implementation using filter() to perform partitioning

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, lambda, quick-sort

```
from operator import ge as greater, lt as lesser

def qsort(L): 
    if len(L) <= 1: return L
    pivot   = L[0]
    sublist = lambda op: [*filter(lambda num: op(num, pivot), L[1:])]

    return qsort(sublist(lesser))+ [pivot] + qsort(sublist(greater))
```

It seems like an overkill to have two `lambdas` in the `sublist` definition. How can I refactor the `sublist` lambda function to not include lambda at all?

Comment: Are you aware that quicksort is conventionally done in-place, for efficiency?

Comment: @200_success yes, I am - this is more an exercise in using the language features!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having one `lambda` in your definition of sublist is perfectly appropriate, but the use of `filter` isn't appropriate because you are going to need a list anyway. You aren't using it wrong, there are just better solutions.

Also, as noted in the other answer, you can avoid repeated slicing `L` by creating a copy of the list on the first run of the function through an optional default argument (see `first` in the code below).

Finally, summing three lists in your return statement is probably less than optimal. With unpacking in Python 3, you can turn this into a single comprehension which should be better in terms of intermediate object creation.

```
from operator import ge, lt

def qsort(L, first=True):
    if len(L) <= 1: 
        return L

    L = L[:] if first else L  
    pivot = L.pop()
    sublist = lambda op: [n for n in L if op(n, pivot)]

    return [*qsort(sublist(lt), False), pivot, *qsort(sublist(ge), False)]
```

Comment: Somewhere in my surfs, there was a mention of a generator function as being relevant to this task. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Eliminating "the other lambda" for comparison:

```
from operator import ge as greaterEqual, lt as lesser

def sublist(L, op, pivot):
    """ return a list of items num from L satisfying op(num, pivot) """
    return [*filter(lambda num: op(num, pivot), L)]

def qsort(L):
    """ return a partition-sorted list of the L's items """
    if len(L) <= 1: return L
    pivot   = L[0]
    t = L[1:]
    return qsort(sublist(t, lesser, pivot)
       ) + [pivot
       ] + qsort(sublist(t, greaterEqual, pivot))
```

("Everything" about comprehension vs. filter and about in-place and slicing has been said.)

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to make a `filter` object a list, use `list`. Also it'd be clearer if you used a list comprehension instead.

```
sublist = lambda op: [num for num in L[1:] if op(num, pivot)]
```

Also, this isn't very efficient, the list comprehension is making a list, and so is `l[1:]`. It'd be better in terms of memory if you instead performed all operations on one list. If you don't want to do that, using `pivot = L.pop()` would allow you to half the amount of list you're making, as then you can use `L` rather than `L[1:]`.

Comment: `L.pop()` would mutate to my incoming list. Is that a good practice? Since some form of filtering is happening, just for academic purposes, how would I weave in a `filter` in combination with a `operator` in the code?